# Python - List all the files and blob inside an Azure Storage Container

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, blobstorage

This is my first post here on StackOverflow, hope it respects the guideline of this community.

I'm trying to accomplish a simple task in Python because even though I'm really new to it, I found it very easy to use.
I have a storage account on Azure, with a lot of containers inside.
Each container contains some random files and/or blobs.

What I'm trying to do, is to get the name of all these files and/or blob and put it on a file.

For now, I got here:

```py
import os, uuid
import sys
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
connection_string = "my_connection_string"
blob_svc = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string)


try:

    print("Azure Blob Storage v" + __version__ + " - Python quickstart sample")
    print("\nListing blobs...")
    containers = blob_svc.list_containers()
    list_of_blobs = []


    for c in containers:
      container_client = blob_svc.get_container_client(c)
      blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
      for blob in blob_list:
        list_of_blobs.append(blob.name)
      file_path = 'C:/my/path/to/file/randomfile.txt'
      sys.stdout = open(file_path, "w")
      print(list_of_blobs)

except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)
```

But I'm having 3 problems:

1. I'm getting the <name_of_ the_blob>/<name_of_the_file_inside>:
   I would like to have just the name of the file inside the blob
2. If in a container there is a blob (or more than 1 blob) + a random file, this script prints only the name of the blob + the name of the file **inside**, skipping the other files outside the blobs.
3. I would like to put all the names of the blobs/files in a .csv file.

But I'm not sure how to do point 3, and how to resolve points 1 and 2.

Cloud some maybe help on this?

Thanks!

Edit:

I'm adding an image here just to clarify a little what I mean when I talk about blob/files

[image: Example of on the containers inside the azure storage account]

Comment: You are talking about files and blobs as if they are different things, but there are no files in azure blob storage (unless you mean azure files). So can you explain what you mean? Are you maybe referring to folders?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I probably made some confusion, because azure call thigs in a way but they show them in another.
For files, I mean video directly uploaded inside the storage container.
So I have:
An azure storage ---> a lot of containers ----> in each I have "folders" and what azure call, Block blob but in fact they are video

Comment: Thing is, inside a container there are only blobs (videos in your case). There are no folders. Folders are a virtual constuct: if you have a blob named video1/57384 the portal will show a folder "video1" but it does that by parsing the names of the blobs. So if you list all the blobs you will get video1/57384 and video2/383764 for example. To get only the last part of the full blob name you will have to manually parse the file name or use something like `os.path.split`

Answer (score 6):

Just to clarify that there are no 2 things such as files or blobs in the Blob Storage the files inside Blob Storage are called blobs. Below is the hierarchy that you can observe in blob storage.

**Blob Storage > Containers > Directories/Virtual Folders > Blobs**

> I'm getting the <name_of_ the_blob>/<name_of_the_file_inside>: I would like to have just the name of the file inside the blob

for this, you can iterate through your container using `list_blobs(<Container_Name>)` taking only the names of the blobs i.e., blob.name. Here is how the code goes when you are trying to list all the blobs names inside a container.

```
generator = blob_service.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME)
for blob in generator:
    print("\t Blob name: "+c.name+'/'+  blob.name)
```

> If in a container there is a blob (or more than 1 blob) + a random file, this script prints only the name of the blob + the name of the file inside, skipping the other files outside the blobs.

you can use iterate for containers using `list_containers()` and then use `list_blobs(<Container_Name>)` for iterating over the blob names and then finally write the blob names to a local file.

> I would like to put all the names of the blobs/files in a .csv file.

A simple `with open('<filename>.csv', 'w') as f write`. Below is the sample code

```
with open('BlobsNames.csv', 'w') as f:
     f.write(<statements>)
```

Here is the complete sample code that worked for us where each blob from every folder will be listed.

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

ACCOUNT_NAME = "<ACCOUNT_NAME>"
SAS_TOKEN='<YOUR_SAS_TOKEN>'

blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME,account_key=None,sas_token=SAS_TOKEN)

print("\nList blobs in the container")
with open('BlobsNames.txt', 'w') as f:
    containers = blob_service.list_containers()
    for c in containers:
        generator = blob_service.list_blobs(c.name)
        for blob in generator:
            print("\t Blob name: "+c.name+'/'+  blob.name)
            f.write(c.name+'/'+blob.name)
            f.write('\n')
```

This works even when there are folders in containers.

**RESULT:**

[image]

**NOTE:** You can just remove `c.name` while printing the blob to file if your requirement is to just pull out the blob names.

Comment: I think it would be much better if you properly address the issue by explaining the concept of virtual folders because that is where the confusion is in this case. As you can see in the question the OP is able to read the blobs already so your answer does not give a solution to the actual issue.

Comment: Thankyou @PeterBons for pointing it out. Have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! 
I'm no sure why, I also tryed with "from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService"
and it doesn't work for me.
The error is:
ImportError: cannot import name 'BlockBlobService' from 'azure.storage.blob'
Thanks also for all the clarification with the blob and container stuff!

Comment: try using Azure-storage-blob, version: 12.3.0 i.e., `pip install azure-storage-blob==2.1.0`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for your reply,

in the end, I took what SwethaKandikonda-MT wrote, and I change it a little bit to fit the connection problem that I had.

Here is what I came up:

```py
import os, uuid
import sys
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__
import csv


connection_string = "my_account_storage_connection_string"
blob_svc = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string)
list_of_blobs = []


print("\nList blobs in the container")
with open('My_path/to/the/file.csv', 'w') as f:
    
    containers = blob_svc.list_containers()
    
    for c in containers:
        container_client = blob_svc.get_container_client(c.name)
        blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
        for blob in blob_list:
            print("\t Blob name: "+c.name +'/'+  blob.name) #this will print on the console
            f.write('/'+blob.name) #this will write on the csv file just the blob name
            f.write('\n')
```